# How Do you combine geometry when exporting as an alembic file and keep the animations of each object?

Tags: animation, export, alembic

I Cant seem to join my mesh as one as it gets rid of all animations so is there a way of exporting as an alembic file and combining the geometry so that i have one mesh that has different animations on it?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using geometry nodes. Put a geometry nodes modifier on one of the meshes, put the rest into a collection, and join them via nodes. Make sure you realize instances.

[image]

After exporting every mesh should maintain it's animation, and should be combined.